# Ansible jinja2 loops over complex structures

Tags: jinja2, ansible

I have this complex variable:

```
vars:
 - data_sources:
    - source1:
         - attrA: foo1
         - attrB: bar1
    - source2:
         - attrA: foo2
         - attrB: bar2
```

and I would like to loop over the structured variable with jinja2 to 
generate some xml:

```
{% for d in {{data_sources}} %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

but I am getting `error: expected token ':', got '}'", 'failed': True}` for the very first line of the for loop. Any idea why and a solution? Thanks

**UPADTE** I made some corrections to the original example.

Comment: At a glance I think you just need some extra white space at `-source1`. Instead it should be `- source1`. And obviously the same for `source2`

Comment: Thanks, but this was just a typo as I was trying to simplify the question. I added the spaces though, but this is not solving the issue.

Answer (score 4):

You must not use curly braces in jinja directives but only in the body:

```
{% for d in data_sources %}
   {{ d['attrA'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Also your `data_sources` is not what it meant to be:

```
vars:
  data_sources:
   - source1:
       attrA: foo1
       attrB: bar1
   - source2:
       attrA: foo2
       attrB: bar2
```

Comment: Thanks, I credited you for answering the question! However, when I run the playbook now I get: ```{'msg': "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: One or more undefined variables: 'dict object' has no attribute 'attrA'", 'failed': True}```. I refer to it as ```{{d.attrA}}```

Comment: edited my answer accordingly, you need to use `{{d['attrA']}}`

Comment: Unfortunately, your latest example does not seem to work. I have seen attempts separating key/value, like:  ```{% for k,v in data_sources %}``` still not working for me. Elsewhere, I read that d['attrA'] is the same as d.attrA, true?

Comment: I see the error now: Your attrs are a list, so it just cannot work, see my updated answer

Comment: Still not working. Did you try it? I am about to give up and just do list.

Comment: Sorry, got autocompletion in my editor, there was another syntax error in your vars: The dash before data sources:
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#id15